# Creating a thread(out of a vector) of a function with arguments

Tags: multithreading, function, vector, arguments, push-back

I have a problem when using a vector of threads. I want to create a thread for each client in a server. So I have function called NewClient that once the connection is started, does all the necessary things for the client. This function is defined like this:

```
  int __cdecl NewClient(SOCKET ListenSocket, SOCKET ClientSocket,  char *recvbuf,  int recvbuflen, int iSendResult, int iResult){
//read command from client
//execute command
//answer the server
}
```

And the vector of threads like this:

```
vector<thread> thred;
```

So the problem comes when I create the thread in the main using the pushback:

```
int __cdecl main(void) {

            //things
             SOCKET ListenSocket=INVALID_SOCKET;
             SOCKET ClientSocket=INVALID_SOCKET;
             char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
             int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
             int iSendResult=0;
             int iResult;
            thred.push_back(thread(NewClient,ListenSocket, ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, iSendResult, iResult));
            thred[thred.size()-1].detach();
    }
```

when using(as far as I know it is used like this) :

```
thred.push_back(thread(NewClient,ListenSocket, ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, iSendResult, iResult));
```

I get two errors, underlining thread:

> Error 2   error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : ninguna función
>   sobrecargada acepta 7 argumentos  D:\Descargas\Baaer 1.0.22\Baaer
>   1.0.22\Server\Server\Source_s.cpp 170 1   Server
>
> 3   IntelliSense: ninguna instancia del constructor
>   "std::thread::thread" coincide con la lista de argumentos
>               los tipos de argumento son: (int __cdecl (SOCKET ListenSocket, SOCKET ClientSocket, char *recvbuf, int recvbuflen, int
>   iSendResult, int iResult), SOCKET, SOCKET, char [512], int, int,
>   int)  d:\Descargas\Baaer 1.0.22\Baaer
>   1.0.22\Server\Server\Source_s.cpp 170 19  Server

So how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39f50623aa335ff8)</kbd>**

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int, double, std::string, bool) {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(10);

    threads.emplace_back(foo, 42, 3.14,  "string", false);
    threads.emplace_back(foo, 52, 13.14, "data",   true);

    for (auto& th : threads)
        if (th.joinable()) 
            th.join();
}
```

Prints

```
foo
foo
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried this but gave C2660 error. And says that:   'std::vector<_Ty>::emplace_back' the function doesn't accept 7 arguments